# L2TPV3 Support out of the box

Tags: networking

I'm looking to do a L2TPv3 Pseudowire over ethernet. The Linux code has been around since 2.6 in the kernel, but Ubuntu doesn't seem to support it without a kernel recompile. What is your suggestion to address the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The `ip` utility is usually built to match specific kernel versions so L2TPV3 probably is not something easily added in the default install. Looking at the bigger Linux version it seems that L2TPv3 is not yet on the radar: [Redhat](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=895791), SUSE,  OpenBSD and Ubuntu do seem to have it in the kernel, but none of them have it enabled.

So options ...

1. Use Ubuntu and compile it yourself. Besides that you could open a bug making a case for it to be included.
2. Use another operating system that does support it out of the box. One distribution that does enable L2TPv3 is Debian Squeeze, but only in their optional 2.6.38/39 kernels.

Answer (score 1):

13.10 (Saucy Salamander) now includes the required kernel modules by default.